# Conflict with pulling information from database into html columns with three SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

The below code does almost exactly what I want visually.  Except Column 1 and Column 2 just show the same picture for all 10 entries, while Column 3 shows a unique entry every Row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Covid-Deaths</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="covid.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f285a5a86.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>You're terrible at this</h1>
<p>Get each picture to be unique</p>

<?php
//database Connection
include 'dbconfig.php';
// retrieving data from table accounts

$query  = "SELECT * FROM test_info where tf = 1 LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$query2  = "SELECT * FROM test_info where tf = 1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$query3  = "SELECT * FROM test_info where tf = 1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);

?>
<?php 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

<div class="container">
<div class="card">
        <a href="<?php echo $row['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo 
$row['picture'];?>" width=80%/></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row['names']; echo ", "; echo $row['age'];?></h4>
        <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row['state']; ?></p>                
</div>

<div class="card">
        <a href="<?php echo $row2['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo 
$row2['picture'];?>" width=80%/></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row2['names']; echo ", "; echo $row2['age'];?></h4>
        <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row2['state']; ?></p>                
</div>

<div class="card">
        <a href="<?php echo $row3['obit_url'];  ?>"><img src="uploaded-images/<?php echo 
$row3['picture'];?>" width=80%/></a>
        <h4><?php echo $row3['names']; echo ", "; echo $row3['age'];?></h4>
        <p><?php echo " "; echo "State: "; echo $row3['state']; ?></p>                
</div>
    
</div>
<?php
 }
    }

 }
    }

 }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of what it outputs:

**Steve Paul Mary**

**Steve Paul John**

**Steve Paul Sam**

What I want it to look like:

**Steve Paul Mary**

**Randy Kyle John**

**Phil  Scott Sam**

I can't seem to get the first and second column to pull in the unique entries that I know are there.

Comment: Why do you need three queries? Why not retrieve 30 in a group, stick the results in an array, then loop through them in groups of ten? Having three queries seems to make things more complicated than they need to be. I don't use mysqli myself (I prefer PDO) but I recall reading about issues when trying to run a new query before the results from a previous query have been retrieved, maybe that's upsetting things.

Comment: You are doing a `WHILE` loop in a `WHILE` loop in a `WHILE` loop, so for the first 10 times you display your 3 cards, the 2 first will stay the same. And by the time you get  to the 2nd iteration of your 2nd loop, there are no more rows to fetch from your 3rd query result, and your next cards are not displayed

Comment: Tabbing your code properly will help you to see why things are going wrong.

Comment: @droopsnoot is there any way you could explain how to do that?  I'll try to do some googling, but again, I'm new with PHP and have little to no idea as to what I'm doing.

Comment: @Pepper thank you for the explanation.  That makes sense as to why it's doing that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the middle `while` loop, the first and second columns will stay the same as you don't fetch a new row for them.

You could change it to 1 `while` loop and just fetch the other rows in this 1 loop...

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
        $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
```

this will fetch all 3 results in the same order.  You would have to know what to do if any of them don't return a value though.